# PC Charging Drivers for Motorola w270

Tags: windows, drivers, phone

I tried installing the PC Charging Drivers on Windows 7 x64 for my w270 phone with instructions from [this site](http://www.motorola.com/Support/GB-EN/Support-Hompage/Software-and-Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers)). I got these errors:

> The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)

[image: Motorola w270 driver error 1]

[image: Motorola w270 driver error 2]